# SIEM CEF format syntax

Tags: syslog

I am new to the SIEM system and currently stuck on a silly issue that I could not find an answer for online, so please help out.

So I am trying to create a CEF type entry. Is following extension is acceptable as per standards?
I have this -

```
cs3Label=infoMap
cs3=[{key1,key2},{key3,key4}]
```

My concern is that is

```
[{...,...} ,{...,...}]
```

allowed with the provided String extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I use this for the CEF format

> CEF:0|MuCompany|MyProduct|MyVersion|FileName %
>   dname=% dst=% dpt=%
>   prot=% src=% spt=% suser=%<=userName>
>   xAuthenticatedUser=% requestMethod=%

The %<  > is replaced with actual data.  Key/Value pairs are separated by = and a space between each set, after the CEF header